# A file on a network drive

Tags: windows-10

I asked a person to print a file. I did not have an USB drive. Thus I put that file in his USB drive. Then he said that he had deleted the file. I find that file in "network drive" of windows 10 explorer. Does it mean that he did not delete the file?

Comment: Likely only if that network drive maps to to the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this, in essence the file randomly appeared on a network drive that was on a USB drive?

If that is the case it is indicative of Offline File Sync.
Press Win+X in combination, chose ‘Control Panel’ from the list of options, type ‘Sync Center’ in the search field and hit ‘Enter’.
Click the ‘Manage offline files’ link highlighted in blue in the left column of your computer screen.
Once done, you will see an Offline Files window pop up on your screen. You are switched to ‘General’ tab by default. Here, check if the offline files are enabled or not. 
Do this on both machines and check for the original file path or file itself. If this is the case then yes he probably did delete the file it was simply a matter of offline file sync reproducing the file in the background.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I went so far to click the offline file but nothing showed up.

Comment: Right click the file you are seeing in Network locations and see if you can view the original location. You might find that it is referencing the usb drive if not. Navigate to the location and manually verify the file is present. Also you may want to check the computer for any 3rd party file synchronization applications such as SugarSync, DropBox, etc. One of these could be the culprit. Let me know if you do not find any third party applications.